# past simple vs. present perfect in context

Tags: grammar

Here is a story in real life.

I am suffering a software issue. When I launch iTunes, some error shows up. I asked about that problem on [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1545893/1100842). someone suggested me to re-install that software. I did what they suggested but it didn't work. So, I said

> I have re-installed iTunes many times. Bonjour Service **never showed up**.

Did I use the tense correctly? Should I use past participle, present perfect or some other?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present perfect tense is needed (*throughout* the sentence):

**I have re-installed iTunes many times. Bonjour Service has never shown up.**

If you use the simple past I will think you have stopped trying:

*I re-installed iTunes many times. Bonjour Service never showed up.*